# Protected View in Microsoft Excel 2010 and Python

Tags: python, linux, excel, view, protected

No code examples here. Just running into an issue with Microsoft Excel 2010 where I have a python script on linux that pulls data from csv files, pushes it into excel, and emails that file to a certain email address as an attachment.

My problem is that I'm using formulas in my excel file, and when it first opens up it goes into "Protected View". My formulas don't load until after I click "Enable Editing". Is there anyway to get my numbers to show up even if Protected Mode is on?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Just used the for loop to keep a running total. Sorry for the wasted question.